# Google Maps Distance Matrix API

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

For the trafficModel parameter (using bestguess), the guide indicates that the returned duration_in_traffic should be the best estimate of travel time given what is known about both historical traffic conditions.

Given the time you enter in secs (as an integer), is the returned travel time based on historical data for that specific day, say a Friday at 6pm over the course of a few weeks, months (or particular month) or even whole year? Anyone have the criteria that the "historical data" is based on? Thanks